# What are the steps for an android app to publish play store and showing admob ads?

Tags: android, admob

I have successfully integrated admob "Test ads" in my android app. Then I created an ad unit in admob and replaced the test app id and test ad unit id with my original app id and original ad unit id. then I just published the app in play store. Now are there any steps remaining to do for showing admob ads in my app.

Comment: Looks like you're good to go, for a pre-release checklist, you might want to read it the official docs here: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9388275?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to go to the app you created in admob (where you created the ad unit), and in its settings you need to link the AdMob app to the PlayStore app.

ps. Months ago this was enough for the ads to run, now I think they have put in a review process where, when you connect the app, they do checks to see if it violates their policies, and if all goes well, they should notify you that everything went well, or else the steps to take to solve the problem. (but I haven't loaded / linking new apps in admob in months, so I'm not sure if they do this process or not, or how long it will take, or whatever, so I recommend you do some research about it).